Subir fotos a cloudinary por orden de selección
tengo un problema con Cloudinary , estoy usando con widget con el script metido en mi index.js de angular  :
  <script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/v2.0/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Me funciona todo correcto , pero lo que yo quiero conseguir es que en el momento que las fotos se están cargando me respete el orden de selección , por ejemplo tu tienes en una carpeta 10 fotos , y seleccionas las 10 de golpe para subir , y las fotos por ejemplo estan etiquetadas asi "IMG_20231016_151501669.jpg" , bien pues desde la primera foto hasta la ultima quiero que respete ese orden de subida , no que suba primero la del medio luego la ultima y después la primera , etc ... , por que lo que yo hago es capturar las urls y guardarla en la BBDD , y por eso necesito que vayan en orden , ya que luego las muestro en el DOM y me interesan mostrarlas en el orden que las haya subido el usuario :
  openCloudinaryUploader(folderPath: string, tags: string[]) {
    console.log('Inicializando subida de imágenes para la carpeta:', folderPath, 'con tags:', tags);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isLoading2 = false;
    }, 1000);
    this.totalImagesToUpload = 0;
    this.uploadedImagesCount = 0;
    const urlsArray: string[] = [];
    const files: any[] = [];
  
    cloudinary.openUploadWidget(
      {
        cloudName: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        uploadPreset: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
        sources: ['local', 'camera', 'url', 'image_search'],
        showAdvancedOptions: true,
        multiple: true,
        defaultSource: 'local',
        folder: folderPath,
        tags: tags,
        styles: {
          palette: {
            window: '#F5F8FA',
            sourceBg: '#FFFFFF',
            windowBorder: '#90A0B3',
            tabIcon: '#0094C7',
            inactiveTabIcon: '#69778A',
            menuIcons: '#0094C7',
            link: '#53AD9D',
            action: '#FF620C',
            inProgress: '#0078FF',
            complete: '#20B832',
            error: '#E4584C',
            textDark: '#000000',
            textLight: '#FFFFFF',
          },
        },
      },
      (error: any, result: any) => {
        console.log('Resultado del widget de subida:', { error, result });
        if (result && result.event === 'upload-added') {
          const file = result.info.file;
          files.push(file);
          console.log('Archivo añadido para subir:', file);
          this.totalImagesToUpload++;
        } else if (result && result.event === 'queues-start') {
          console.log('Inicio de la subida en cola.');
          console.log('Archivos en el orden seleccionado:', files);
          this.uploadImagesSequentially(files, folderPath, tags, urlsArray);
        } else if (result && result.event === 'success') {
          console.log('Imagen subida con éxito:', result.info.url);
          urlsArray.push(result.info.url);
          console.log('urlsArray después de agregar nueva URL:', urlsArray);
          this.uploadedImagesCount++;
          console.log('uploadedImagesCount:', this.uploadedImagesCount);
          console.log('totalImagesToUpload:', this.totalImagesToUpload);
        } else if (result && result.event === 'queues-end') {
          console.log('Todas las subidas han terminado. Guardando URLs...');
          let folderType: 'inicio' | 'durante' | 'final' | 'parteTrabajo' | null = null;
          if (folderPath === 'montadores/inicio/') {
            folderType = 'inicio';
          } else if (folderPath === 'montadores/durante/') {
            folderType = 'durante';
          } else if (folderPath === 'montadores/final/') {
            folderType = 'final';
          } else if (folderPath === 'montadores/parteTrabajo/') {
            folderType = 'parteTrabajo';
          }
  
          console.log('folderType:', folderType);
          console.log('urlsArray:', urlsArray);
  
          if (folderType && urlsArray.length > 0) {
            console.log('Llamando a saveUrls con:', folderType, urlsArray);
            this.saveUrls(folderType, urlsArray);
          } else {
            console.log('No se guardan URLs debido a que folderType o urlsArray son inválidos');
            if (!folderType) {
              console.log('folderType es inválido:', folderType);
            }
            if (urlsArray.length === 0) {
              console.log('urlsArray está vacío:', urlsArray);
            }
          }
        } else if (error) {
          console.error('Error en el widget de subida de Cloudinary:', error);
        }
      }
    );
  }



  uploadImagesSequentially(files: any[], folderPath: string, tags: string[], urlsArray: string[]) {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      console.log('No hay más archivos para subir. Procesamiento completado.');
      return;
    }
  
    const file = files.shift();
    console.log('Subiendo imagen:', file);
  
    // Asegurarse de que el objeto `cloudinary` esté disponible y se esté utilizando el método correcto.
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(file, {
      upload_preset: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
      folder: folderPath,
      tags: tags,
    }).then((result: any) => {
      console.log('Resultado de la subida:', result);
      if (result && result.secure_url) {
        console.log('URL de la imagen subida:', result.secure_url);
        urlsArray.push(result.secure_url);
        console.log('urlsArray después de agregar nueva URL:', urlsArray);
        this.uploadedImagesCount++;
        console.log('uploadedImagesCount:', this.uploadedImagesCount);
        console.log('totalImagesToUpload:', this.totalImagesToUpload);
      }
      this.uploadImagesSequentially(files, folderPath, tags, urlsArray);
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
      this.uploadImagesSequentially(files, folderPath, tags, urlsArray);
    });
  }


  saveUrls(folderType: 'inicio' | 'durante' | 'final' | 'parteTrabajo', urls: string[]) {
    console.log('Saving URLs:', folderType, urls);
    if (this.selectedTrabajo) {
      this.usuarioService
        .saveImageUrls(this.selectedTrabajo.ordenfab, folderType, urls)
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            console.log('Respuesta al guardar URLs:', response);
            this.fotosInicio = [];
            this.fotosDurante = [];
            this.fotosFinalizadas = [];
            this.fotosFin = [];
            this.fotosParteTrabajo = [];
            this.isLoading2 = true;
            this.refreshTrabajos();
  
            timer(8000).subscribe(() => {
              this.isLoading2 = false;
  
              const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmDialogComponent, {
                data: {
                  title: 'ACEPTA LA ACCION',
                  message: 'Subida realizada correctamente',
                  showCancelButton: false,
                },
              });
  
              dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
                if (result) {
                  this.dialog.closeAll();
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    this.refreshTrabajos();
                  }, 1500);
                }
              });
            });
          },
          (error) => {
            this.toastr.error('Error guardando las URLs');
            console.error(`Error guardando las URLs de ${folderType}`, error);
            this.isLoading2 = false;
          }
        );
    } else {
      console.log('No hay trabajo seleccionado para guardar las URLs');
    }
  }



Tienes un objeto con los objetos que ha seleccionado el usuario, que está en el orden que quieres mostrarlas... por qué no las muestras a partir de ese objeto y te evitas pelearte con el orden de las subidas? De hecho, personalmente no haría la subida una a una si no que las haría en paralelo para ahorrar tiempo de espera al usuario, y luego las muestras a partir del array de seleccionadas (filtrándolo si hay alguna que ha fallado por ejemplo).

No se si es proyecto personal o de trabajo, pero me parece que es mucho código para subir imágenes a cloudinary, tal vez te simplificaría la vida usar el modulo para Angular en lugar del widget de Cloudinary.

mi objetivo con esto era poder respetar el orden de selección al momento de subir las fotos a Cloudinary , me puse en contacto con el Support de Cloudinary y me han dicho que no se puede , por que el momento de la subida de fotos , tiene un proceso interno con la api y con el widget que sube todas las fotos los mas rápidamente sin importar el orden de selección .
La otra opción que encontré es que en el momento de la descarga de las fotos , con la fecha de captura de la foto ordenarlas y asignarles un nombre 0001 , 0002 , 0003 ETC ... según el momento de la captura. Para que Cloudinary te respete todos los metadatos en la configuración del widget no tienes que tener ningún tipo de compresión y luego con la librería EXIF extraes los datos que quieras , se pueden extraer con Cloudinary , pero no te recoge todos los metadatos , la librería EXIF te compone los datos , por que te lo trae todo en binario , y ya esta.
Comento la solución que encontré yo a mi problema , pero seguro se puede hacer con el problema expuesto al inicio .
